Loop through range variables to summarize written code
I am looking for a way to optimize this chunk of code:
Sub ClipBoardtoNotePad()

Dim lastRow, i, a As Integer

Dim CopyRng1, CopyRng2, CopyRng3, CopyRng4, CopyRng5, CopyRng6, CopyTotal As Range

Dim ws, ws2 As Worksheet

Dim col As Long

Dim CopyData, CopyDataTempFile, pathtonotepad, pathtotestfile, username As String
    
    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet2
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    

    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' getting last written row, to retrieve only written range
    With CopyRng1
    Set CopyRng1 = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)) ' defining copying range, in accordance to lastRow
    CopyRng1.Copy ' range copy
    Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate
    Range("Separator1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' getting last written row, to retrieve only written range
    With CopyRng2
    Set CopyRng2 = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2)) ' defining copying range, in accordance to lastRow
    CopyRng2.Copy ' range copy
    Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate
    Range("Separator0").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' getting last written row, to retrieve only written range
    With CopyRng3
    Set CopyRng3 = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3)) ' defining copying range, in accordance to lastRow
    CopyRng3.Copy ' range copy
    Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate
    Range("Separator3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row ' getting last written row, to retrieve only written range
    With CopyRng4
    Set CopyRng4 = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lastRow, 4)) ' defining copying range, in accordance to lastRow
    CopyRng4.Copy ' range copy
    Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate
    Range("Separator4").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row ' getting last written row, to retrieve only written range
    With CopyRng5
    Set CopyRng5 = Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(lastRow, 5)) ' defining copying range, in accordance to lastRow
    CopyRng5.Copy ' range copy
    Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate
    Range("FINAL").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row ' getting last written row, to retrieve only written range
    With CopyRng6
    Set CopyRng6 = Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(lastRow, 6)) ' defining copying range, in accordance to lastRow
    CopyRng6.Copy ' range copy
    Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate
    Range("Separator0").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    
    With CopyTotal
    Worksheets("ReadytoCP").Activate
    lastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set CopyTotal = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)) ' defining copying range, in accordance to lastRow
    CopyTotal.Copy ' range copy
    End With

Any suggestions on how to do so?
Also, as you can see, I have quite a few "Wait" functions throughout this process: This was trying to mitigate a problem within clipboard, where it would pop up a message saying "Not able to utilize clipboard as it is still being used by another process" (something in this lines).
My guess was that it was a lot of information for clipboard to process in a faster way and it would still be copying stuff while the macro was already requesting for Paste.
I tried this:
Dim CopyRanges (1 To 6) As Range
Dim i, aAs Integer

Set CopyRanges(1) = CopyRng1
etc
etc

For i = LBound(copyRanges) To UBound(copyRanges)
lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, a).End(xlUp).Row ' getting last written row, to retrieve only written range
    With copyRanges(i)
    Set copyRanges(i) = Range(Cells(2, a), Cells(lastRow, a)) ' defining copying range, in accordance to lastRow
    copyRanges(i).Copy ' range copy
    Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate
    Range("Separator1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
Next i
Next a

This would enter almost in an infinite Loop and would paste the same thing a lot of times....Maybe the way I wrote 'Next i and Next a"?
Please, if someone can also confirm my question related to ClipBoard (see above), that would also help!

Please explain with plain words and a sample input what your intention is, whether your code is correct, if not, what is making it imprecise, if yes, what the problem is (performance?)?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Some recommendations below:
Option Explicit ' use this option for clarity; use Debug-->Compile to verify the code

Sub ClipBoardtoNotePad()
  
  ' Dim lastRow, i, a As Integer - type declaration should be with every variable
  Dim lastRow&, i&, a& ' use symbols for type declaration
  ' Dim CopyRng1 As Range, CopyRng2 As Range, CopyRng3 As Range, CopyRng4 As Range
  ' Dim CopyRng5 As Range, CopyRng6 As Range, CopyTotal As Range
  ' Dim CopyRng As Range - singe variable should be sufficient for everything, not required
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet ' , ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim col As Long
  Dim CopyData$, CopyDataTempFile$, pathtonotepad$, pathtotestfile$, username$
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' disable screen updating to save much time
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' can be applyed
  Application.EnableEvents = False ' if event handling (like Worksheet_Change) is applyed
  
  
  Set ws1 = Sheet1
  ' Set ws2 = Sheet2 - not required
    
  ' Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    
  ' Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate - don't use if not mandatory required

  ' lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  ' With CopyRng1 - wrong, the variable is not itialized yet, but it doesn't cause an error
    ' Set CopyRng1 = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)) moved up
    ' CopyRng1.Copy
    ' Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate - not required
    ' Range("Separator1").Select - not required
    ' Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown - below
    ' Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Range("Separator1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
  ' End With
  
  ' Set CopyRng = ws1.[A2].Resize(lastRow - 1, 1) ' use woksheet variable; use Resize to define a range of many cells
  ' With CopyRng ' wrong, the variable is not itialized yet, but it doesn't cause an error
    ' Set CopyRng1 = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)) moved up
    ' .Copy ' use With block
    ' Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Activate - not required
    ' Range("Separator1").Select - not required
    ' Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown - below
    ' Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Range("Separator1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
  ' End With
  
  ws1.[A2].Resize(ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1).Copy
  Worksheets("ReadyToCP").Range("Separator1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

  ' ...

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


You can mark the answer as accepted if it helps.
